# Each feature's weights to the output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used several time series as features (3 features as input) into LSTM model (1 output on regression) on TF 1.1.0. The main function started a session as below:

```
model = SKCompat(learn.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model, 
              model_dir=LOG_DIR,
              params={'learning_rate': Learning_rate}))
model.fit(trainX, trainY, steps=steps)
```

and the lstm_model function as below mainly:

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=0.1)
(output, state) = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, inputs=features, dtype=tf.float32)
```

After training and saving the model (saved automatically by the default tf function itself), I could read the weights of the LSTM cell by 'import_meta_graph' and 'restore' in the main function. The weights looks like a (131, 512) array.

The problem is how to know the weights of each feature from such a weights array, i.e. each feature's weights to the output?

Comment: Explain: If I add one more feature to the input, the weights will be (132,512) array.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking here. Are you asking how much effect each weight has on what the output of the LSTM will be at a given time step? If so, you can look up sensitivity analysis for neural networks, but there is no exact answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But not all. As I know, the output in the lstm model is like o=tanh(WiXi + Uh + b). I actually want to know the W value of each X (Xs is called features). Or W‘s final result.